# Transform images into a circular variant, changing circle size and place

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image-processing

I love the circular profile pictures, but I hate that you cant edit them. Say for example you dont want the circle in the middle and the standard size, but you want it smaller or something.

Explanation with pictures:

[The 4 images, from bottom to top: input, image editor, moving circle, output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZP4b.jpg)

Now, I want that you put a normal image in and that there will be a black overlay with some kind of opacity. In the middle you'll have a transparent circle so you can select the part you want in the circle. Then you can press save and there will be a .png file made.

I was thinking of doing this with jQuery watermarks, but I couldn't figure it out. Anyone got a idea?

Comment: try looking into canvas and SVG. It shouldn't be to difficult to use the image as a background image and then do some canvas or svg work on it.

Comment: try googling for a cropping script

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods:

You can use CSS2/3 - with `corner-radius` (for newer browsers) or even just an overlay image, image can be cropped, and background can be scaled/moved via CSS `background-position` and `background-size` accordingly. To save the image, you'll need a minimalistic PHP script do do the same operation server-side (given the parameters) and output the image to user.

You can also use HTML5 canvas - specification involves a handy `clip` method (which is straightforward - limits drawn imagery to current path), and you can obtain the image data via `toDataURL` method of canvas element as long as image is uploaded to the same server (or cross-domain rules are done right). A minimal search on saving files from JS+HTML5 should further assist.

Sample jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u2A7t/